# Как правильно запустить Run Build Task в VS Code с параметрами (запуск mingw)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Я только начал. Вот что методом тыка написал:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "mingw32_g++",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw32\\bin\\mingw32-g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-std=c++11",
                "-Wall",
                "-O3",
                "-DUNICODE",
                "-I","${workspaceFolder}\\include\\",
                "-I","${workspaceFolder}\\source\\",
                "-c",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\.objects\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.obj"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Работает, но нужно подключить ещё один include dir

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "mingw32_g++",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw32\\bin\\mingw32-g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-std=c++11",
                "-Wall",
                "-O3",
                "-DUNICODE",
                "-I","${workspaceFolder}\\include\\",
                "-I","${workspaceFolder}\\source\\",
                "-I","${workspaceFolder}\\thirdparty\\libliblib-1.0.0\\src\\include\\",
                "-c",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\.objects\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.obj"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Ошибка:

> The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1

Comment: Ответ должен быть размещен как ответ, а не в теле вопроса.

Comment: @Kromster сайт мне подсказал что нужно было просто дополнить ответ

Comment: Вы на сайте не первый день, пора бы уже знать как он работает ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При запуске процесса, нужно было указать рабочую папку, чтобы были видны остальные программы и библиотеки из набора MinGW.

```
    "tasks": [
    {
        "label": "32_compile_g++",
        "type": "process",
        "options": {
            "cwd": "C:\\msys64\\mingw32\\bin\\"
        },
        "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw32\\bin\\mingw32-c++.exe",
        "args": [
            "-std=c++11",
            "-Wall",
            "-O3",
            "-DUNICODE",
            "-I",
            "${workspaceFolder}\\include\\",
            "-I",
            "${workspaceFolder}\\source\\",
            "-I",
            "${workspaceFolder}\\thirdparty\\libliblib\\src\\headers\\",
            "-c",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\.objects\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.obj"
        ],
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    },
```